# Why are applications like brave browser, spotify, atom etc. opening slowly?

Tags: 18.04

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and the applications like brave browser, spotify, atom, chrome etc. open slowly when opened for the first time after booting the system, but gets normal after the second attempt. How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: snap app can have some delay to open

Comment: @cmak.fr as far as I know, Google Chrome can only be installed from Google's repository and that is not a snap app. chromium seems to be available as snap app for 18.04.